# Find the mismatch between two python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, runtime, memory-efficient

I have two dataframe below:

df1>>

[image]

df2>>

[image]

I need to compare the two dataframe and find the id's in col1 where col2 value is a mismatch i.e. for the sample dataset 3 should be the answer.

Please note in the actual problem I have 10^6 number of unique id's in col 1 hence if-else ladder or running loop at each unique col1 key level is taking a very long execution time. I am looking for an efficient method to do this. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Hi there! It's greatly appreciated if you don't post data as image, but as proper text, and especially for dataframes, there are some [well established conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/15873043).

Answer (score 1):

You can compare dataframes with [`pd.DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html).

```py
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], "col2": list("ABCDEF")})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], "col2": list("ABDCEK")})
>>> df1.compare(df2)
  col2      
  self other
2    C     D
3    D     C
5    F     K
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 1,2,2,3,3] ,"col2": ['A','B','C','D','E','F']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 1,2,2,3,3] ,"col2": ['A','B','D','C','E','K']})
df3 = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer').query('_merge != "both"').drop('_merge', 1)
df3
```

[image]